# Esp32-wroom-32E stop connecting to WiFi

Tags: wifi, esp32, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32, esp8266wifi

I am working on a project i.e. Energy Meter in which Esp32_wroom-32E is being used by me. When I install the device in clients homes. they work fine for a week or so and then Wifi connection issues start. I had also run a timer which checks every 3 minutes if WiFi is connected or not. It tries to disconnect and again connects to WiFi. But sometimes the device does'nt connect. What can be issue.

I tried to run a loop to check WiFi connectivity and then try to connect if not but it seems like some other issue.

Comment: It might be excessive noise in the vicinity (microwave oven or so), or something affecting the environment so the power of the signal goes very low. In my opinion your only workaround is to add a check in the main loop for connectivity, and a robust function to reconnect even if the connection phase fails. nobody is safe from wifi disconnects...

Comment: It is installed near Home Electric DB to read Grid current and voltage.

Comment: That should not be an issue for wifi. I was thinking about 2.4GHz sources of noise (CB Radio, Microwave ovens,...)

Comment: And what is the solution to minimize such issues.

Comment: If you're using a version of the ESP32 with PCB antenna, try to modify it to a physical antenna, search for "extend ESP32 wifi range" to learn the various ways to do it (usually it needs soldering and attaching a physical antenna).